# How to remove scrollbars on parent with IE8 and FancyBox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have successfully set up the FancyBox, and it works like a charm on Chrome.
However,[I get strange scrollbars on IE8 when I open the ajax Content](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/2917/83709167.jpg)  (happens with other content as well I think). Does anyone know why and how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

I used the newer version of Fancybox (as of 11/16/2012)

To fix this problem, go to `jquery.fancybox.js` and on line 1229, change

```
origHeight = body.height();
```

to

```
origHeight = body.height()+10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your curtains css to `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Thank you, but assuming #fancybox-overlay in the FancyBox CSS is the curtain, it doesn't change anything. Please have a look at the [CSS](http://idesignz.de/hhb/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.3), I can't find anything that might fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I created a dirty "workaround"

```
beforeShow  : function () { 
            $('body').addClass('alter_body'); 
    },
beforeClose : function () { 
            $('body').removeClass('alter_body'); 
    }
```

the "alter_body" contains `overflow:hidden`

Works for me, any cleaner solutions appreciated

Comment: I don't think it is fancybox creating those scroll bars. If that is only happening on IE, most likely there are floating elements on either inside the fancybox (where fancybox has fixed dimensions but the content is bigger and/or floating inside of it) or in the body tag. What type of content are you opening inside fancybox (ajax, inline, iframe)?

Comment: It's Ajax content but the content.php currently it only consists of <?php echo $test;?> nothing else. There are DIVs in the body, but none floating?! And yes, it's only IE.